# How does one get the Note icon bigger so it can be used?

Tags: notes

I really don't have any idea what I need to do or even what I have here!  I do know I have (I think) Ubuntu 16.04.  It's pretty much a new install and everything is pretty much default.  I have, I guess it's called a taskbar on the left side and it has some Widgets.  I really would like to have a Note Widget and you know, have notes and make this OS useful.  I click on the Notes Widget and try to open that thing bigger than a 1"x1" square.  I am able to put some texts on it but I need the thing like maybe the size of a page.  I right click the icon and gives all this useful stuff on it like White, Black, Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Pink, Translucent, Note settings and Panel Options.  Note settings have options for these other pretty colors and looks like setting up keyboard shortcuts.  The last option is Panel Options with 5 other options.  None of which would get me something boring like a big useful page to write notes on, but I do have and found alot of pretty colors to set my 1"x1" square!

Does this thing have anything more than pretty colors to offer?  How does one actually write stuff like notes on it?

Comment: Do you have the name of the program you've installed? What functionality are you looking for? Have you considered xpad? It's in the official repos and I guess people like it. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/xpad-simple-sticky-notes-for-your-desktop

Comment: Please take a scrrenshot and attach it

Comment: This came with the OS.  I think, but I'm not sure, but I think I have 16.04 and I have a K at the bottom left corner.  I know in Windows you would more than likely right click on the icon in question and be able to view the properties of the item.  On this OS, that's not an option.  I change the colors though!

Comment: I can't take a scrrenshot cause I don't know how.

Comment: I am looking at being able to write notes easliy.  I don't want to be looking for the program, I don't want to have to open or click a bunch of clicks to write one or two sentences, and more than likely, I'll want to view these notes at some time during the week.  I really don't need a "Notes" app that has bunch choices on colors, but absolutely nothing on how to make it bigger than a 1"x1" size.

Comment: This post makes me sooooooooo sad  :-(.